# Guidelines for writing automation scripts in Selenium Java

Tags: java, automated-tests, ui-automation

I need some Guidelines for writing selenium automation scripts in java

I have identified the following

1) Put relevant comments
 2) Surround code with try/catch
 3) Don't repeat code
 4) Split code into short focused units 
 5) Be consistent

Please suggest if there are any more. Thanks

Comment: While I feel like this is mostly off topic under the guidelines of "find me a tool or library", you might find the rules that come with SonarQube(highly recommended) or PMD of interest(It was just OK).  https://www.sonarqube.org/  https://pmd.github.io/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are some of the links I have found for Guidelines

http://www.techbeamers.com/java-coding-guidelines-coding-style/#java-exception-handling

Answer (score 1):

Try catch might be useful in test framework code, but try to avoid using it in the tests itself.

In general, if there is a condition in your test that throws an Exception, then you want your test to fail with that specific Exception. I.e. if we have a scenario that includes logging in and the login button is not present, then we want to fail it straight away on the failed click of the login button. Ignoring the failure and continuing is pointless.

There can also be situations where the application under test is unpredictable. You can sometimes make constructions with a try catch and a retry to get the test to pass consistently. However, it is still preferred to talk with a developer to try to get the behavior of the application under test more predictable. In this way you can keep your tests simpler and understandable and every time it is run you are really testing the same thing.